# How to check string for colon and split to get first index if it has colon

Tags: java, guava

I have a `String` which will be either in these two forms:

- `prefix:abcdefg`
- `abcdefg`

I need to check whether my String contains `:` and if it contains `:` then split on colon and get first index which is `abcdefg` but if it doesn't contains `:` then use the string as it is which is `abcdefg`. So I have below code which does the same thing.

```
holder.getClientId().contains(":") ? holder.getClientId().split(":")[1] : holder.getClientId()
```

Is there any better way of doing above things using Guava Splitter or any other way?

Assuming `holder.getClientId()` cannot be null or empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way would be not to use `split` but take the substring starting from the first index of `:` (+ 1).

- If the colon isn't found, [`indexOf(':')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) will return `-1` and you can start the [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) at `0`.
- If the colon is found, it will return its `index` and you can start at `index + 1` to ignore it.

A sample code would be:

```
String partAfterDot = str.substring(str.indexOf(':') + 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like:

```
public static String getPartAfterColon(String text){
    return text.substring(text.indexOf(':')+1);
}
```

Demo:

```
System.out.println(getPartAfterColon("prefix:abcdefg")); //"abcdefg"
System.out.println(getPartAfterColon("abcdefg"));        //"abcdefg"
System.out.println(getPartAfterColon(""));               //""
System.out.println(getPartAfterColon(":"));              //""
```